# Moderating non stop comments

Tags: 6, comments

I'm sick of moderating comments in my sites. Currently in Admin I'd see all comment titles with view/edit link on each. 
What I want a table in which I can see each comment full text(which I can edit) along with delete/approval buttons so that I can moderate all of them at once in single screen.

Is there any module which can give me this view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views). :)

Just create yourself a comment-based view and configure it the way you want. I guess you won't be able to have an in-place editing here, but everything else should be easy achievable.

Comment: Better yet use Views Bulk Operations and you can take actions on many comments at once.

Comment: Actually, you should try [Admin VBO Views](http://drupal.org/project/admin_vbo_views), which is a feature module with VBO views for administering comments, nodes, and users.

Comment: Thanks, but currently I'm on D6